# How To Store / Query Data In VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

At the moment I am using `Access` & an `OleDb` connection to store data. I went down this route originally because I though that this was the best way for applications that I am distributing to my clients.

I would prefer to use something like SQL Server but is this a good idea for software I am distributing? Does the average Joe's PC have SQL Server pre-installed? If not, I suppose I can provide them with a link to download it for free?

Is there any better alternatives to Access / SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341.aspx) and bundle the database with your application.

See [this How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really given enough information to answer this specifically but I'll answer generally:

> Does the average Joe's PC have SQL Server pre-installed?

No.

> If not, I suppose I can provide them with a link to download it for free?

Yes, Microsoft has fairly generous 'free' versions of SQL server Express for small database sizes (<1GB) and small numbers of CPU's (1).  Check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx).

> Are there any better alternatives to Access / SQL Server?

It depends on your app, your skill and how you define better.

If you are running sql-server you can very easily use linq2sql and have strongly typed data base objects that offer clean vb.net code. The [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) technologies are worth learning IMO. The tools in VS2010 work well with sql-server databases.  Other more modern Microsoft tools are available too that integrate very easily (entity framework and lightswitch (which I don't have experience with)).

For small local databases [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) works well.  If your project is very small and the sql is simple this is a very light weight solution.  This is very small and very fast and is used everywhere.

If a server is needed and low cost matters [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/)is a solid open source server though it is now under private ownership.

Again depending upon your application off-site hosting of a database might be a viable solution.  I have a client that is still running their db in the cloud with a low cost 2008 SQL Server provider.